# Difference in group means with repeated observations

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, autocorrelation

I’m by no means a beginner in stats but this is a very basic question after twenty years of not practicing my studies!

I have five years of monthly data for a universe of companies, say 1600 companies. The universe of companies is not constant (in number or the specific constituents).

At each time period I have a score for each company. The score change over time but there is auto-correlation.

I’d like to know if companies in country A tend to have a significantly different score to the full universe.

I’ve calculated the average score for each country at each time point. I’ve calculated the average of these averages and I’m on the verge of doing some sort of t-test on these…but something feels wrong.

What’s the appropriate test statistic here, or am I missing a bigger thing?

Comment: Yes, you've got non-independence in your data that you're not accounting for appropriately: (1) multiple measurements per company over time, and (2) some countries are more similar than others, by virtue of geographical distance and cultural connection. Mixed models are a common approach for this kind of data but there are other solutions. If you describe your data in more detail (and maybe include a data sample), you may be more likely to get a useful answer.